# About topological Tor-vanishing.

Tags: functional-analysis

My question concern a certain topological Tor functor.

Can someone say me if this assumption is true:
Let E be a Souslin lcs which is complete bornological topological space (and then a direct limit of  Banach space)  and

-F be   a (strong) dual of Frechet nuclear space

We assume further that this two  spaces are modules over Stein algebra  A.

CLAIM: the topological tor,  Tor^{A}_{j}(E, F)=0.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This article of O. Varol might be interesting for you: https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/studia-mathematica/all/180/1/89957/on-the-derived-tensor-product-functors-for-df-and-frechet-spaces

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Jochen. Unfortunately, it does'nt work in my setting.